# How can I access a self-signed webserver using SSL but from another computer on LAN?

Tags: express, ssl, websocket, certificate, lan

Problem: Since Chrome updated a while back (version 58?), I'm not able to access my computer's development Express web server with HTTPS from a remote machine on the same private LAN.

I have created a self-signed certificate on the server (my laptop), and it works great from the same machine via https://localhost:8383 (the local SSL port).

In the past I could bypass the warning on a remote machine on the same network but it has stopped working.

I've gone through the steps of creating a local secure DNS server on my own router with DD-WRT, and self-signed a new certificate with SAN so I could use a DNS host name to access it without specifying an IP address.

I'm able to get to the page after bypassing the message that warns the site's SSL certificate could not be verified. But that's not good enough because while the site will load, the underlying websocket service I'm using on the same port *does not* work, and so the application loads but is broken on the remote machine. Still works on the local machine because the certificate is valid.

It seems the issue centers around Websockets within Express.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! This is a strictly secure environment that's meant to be used on a private network and it makes no sense for me to spend a bunch of money on a public certificate if that even matters.

Thank you.

Comment: You want to access localhost from remote device for debugging ?

Comment: I want to access my laptop from an ipad on the same network. My laptop is serving a NodeJS Express web client to the ipad (or any client for that matter). The client then uses websockets to communicate with my laptop. I should clarify -- when accessing the laptop from the ipad, I'm using https://192.168.x.x:8383 -- it loads the initial page but prompts me that it's not from a trusted location. The initial HTML page loads after I authorize this in Chrome. But the websocket never works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue is with mobile Chrome and Safari on IOS -- I can get untrusted SSL certificates to work with websockets from another computer on the same network with the latest versions of Chrome and Safari. But on IOS (ipads and iphones), the page will load after being prompted, but Websockets FAIL to function whatsoever.

I've found a couple other people finding this issue.

My workaround for this problem was to revert away from SSL for my private network and completely avoid self-signed certificates.

In a private environment this is OK.